# Quick question on localization of tensor products

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

All rings are commutative with unit.

Let $\rho:A\rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism. Suppose $\mathfrak q$ is a prime ideal of $B$, and let $\mathfrak p=\rho^{-1}(\mathfrak q)$.

My question: Is $B_\mathfrak q$ a localization of $B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak p$, or is it equal to  $B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak p$?

I suspect they are equal, but the book I am reading claims  $B_\mathfrak q$ is only a localization of $B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak p$.

Here is my reasoning: Let $S=A-\mathfrak p$. Then $B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak p \cong B\otimes_A S^{-1}A$. This last module is canonically isomorphic to $S^{-1}B$, which is just $B_\mathfrak q$.

Edit: @wxu has kindly pointed out the error in my reasoning. How do I show the claimed fact, then?

Comment: The localization of $B$ at $\mathfrak{q}$ is $T^{-1}B$ where $T=B-\mathfrak{q}$ NOT $S$..

Comment: @wxu Oh, I see. How do I fix this?

Comment: As an example, $B=\mathbb{Q}[T]$, $A=\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathfrak{q}=(T)$ so $\mathfrak{q}\cap A=(0)=\mathfrak{p}$, $B_{\mathfrak{q}}\neq B_{\mathfrak{p}}$.

Comment: Your textbook is right, $B_q$ is a localization of $B_p=B\otimes_A A_p$, since the multiplicative set becomes bigger.

Comment: @wxu Could you provide some more details? I am new to localizations and tensor products. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @wxu In particular, I do not see how the multiplicative set gets "bigger", as $A-p$ and $B-q$ lie in different rings.

Comment: OK, when we compare two sets, we should make them comparable, so $S=A-p$  should read as $\rho(A-p)$. There is an exercise $B_p$ is isomorphic to $\rho(A-p)^{-1}B$. So we read $S$ as a subset of $B$, and $S\subset T$, there is also an exercise says $T^{-1}B$ is isomorphic to the localization of $S^{-1}B$ with the multiplicative set $S^{-1}T$. Those exercises should appear in your book in the same chapter I believe. :)

Comment: @wxu Thank you! If you write those comments as an answer below, I would be happy to accept and upvote it.