# Prove $A_\mathfrak{p} \otimes_A B_\mathfrak{q} = B_\mathfrak{q}$, where $\mathfrak{q}$ prime in $B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

$\require{AMScd}$
Hi,

I think I have the answer for this question, but I'm not sure if it's correct. So I would be very glad if someone could have a quick look through it.

> Let $A$, $B$ be commutative rings, $f: A \to B$ be a ring homomorphism; given $\mathfrak{q}$ prime in $B$, and $\mathfrak{p} = f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$. Prove that: $A_\mathfrak{p} \otimes_A B_\mathfrak{q} = B_\mathfrak{q}$.

I know my question is somewhat similar to this one [Quick question on localization of tensor products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408957/quick-question-on-localization-of-tensor-products).

It's not homework really. I'm reading *Commutative Algebra* by *N. Bourbaki*, and it's a part of the proof to **Proposition 19**, on page 107. In the text, Bourbaki refers that the result comes from the fact that $A \to B \to B_{\mathfrak{q}}$ factors into $A \to A_{\mathfrak{p}} \to B_{\mathfrak{q}}$, since the following diagram commutes:
$\begin{CD}
A @>f>> B\\
@Vi_{\mathfrak{p}}^AVV @VVi_{\mathfrak{q}}^BV\\
A_{\mathfrak{p}} @>f'>> B_{\mathfrak{q}}
\end{CD}$
. However, I don't really know how this fact relates to the result. $\color{blue}{\mathbf{(?)}}$

---

Using the link above, I try to prove that fact. And here's my try:

$$\begin{align*}
B_{\mathfrak{q}} &= [i_{\mathfrak{q}}^B(B\backslash\mathfrak{q})]^{-1}(B_{\mathfrak{p}})\\
&= [i_{\mathfrak{q}}^B(B\backslash\mathfrak{q})]^{-1}(B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p})\\
&= (A_\mathfrak{p}\otimes_A B) \otimes_\color{red}{B} B_{\mathfrak{q}}\\
&= A_\mathfrak{p}\otimes_A B_{\mathfrak{q}}
\end{align*}$$

Where the map $i_{\mathfrak{q}}^B : B \to B_{\mathfrak{q}}$ is the canonical homomorphism.

Although, it gives the correct result. I'm still a little bit unsure about the $\color{red}{B}$ in red above. Since, in the first step, we localize $B$ at $\mathfrak{p}$, which gives us the $A_\mathfrak{p}-$module $B\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}$. I know it's also a $B-$module, but since we've taken the localization, I have a feeling that I should put $A_\mathfrak{p}$ in the red place, instead of $B$. But again, if I put it there, it just won't give the desired result. It would, give me back something like $B \otimes_A B_{\mathfrak{q}}$. :(((( I don't think it's correct either... :( $\color{blue}{\mathbf{(?)}}$

Tensor product is driving me insane. :(

Thank you very much for your help,

And have a good day,

Comment: How do you obtain the third equality in your proof?

Comment: Even shorter than the answer below: the elements of $A-\mathfrak p$ are units in $B_{\mathfrak q}$.

Comment: @user121097: Hi, at first I thought I understood what you said, but then, I'm not so sure. I know that if $S \subset A$ only consists of invertible elements of $A$, then $A = S^{-1}A$, so applying here, we can get: $B_\mathfrak{q} = (A- \mathfrak{p})^{-1}B_\mathfrak{q}$. But how does that relate to $A_\mathfrak{p} \otimes_A B_\mathfrak{q}$? I also tried to prove that the homomorphism $i: B_\mathfrak{q} \to A_\mathfrak{p} \otimes_A B_\mathfrak{q} $, sending each $b \in B_\mathfrak{q}$ to $1 \otimes b$ is an bijection, but failed. Am I missing something here? :(

Comment: $S^{-1}A\otimes_AX\simeq S^{-1}X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what i think is an elegant way to show this equality: It is a general fact (try proving it as an exercise) that for a ring $A$ and a multiplicative set $S$ of $A$, the tensor product of two $A_S$ modules $M, N$ over $A$ is the same as the tensor product over $A_S$. In other words $M \otimes_{A} N  = M \otimes_{A_S} N$. Now both $A_p, B_q$ are $A_p$-modules (and $A$-modules as well) and so $A_p \otimes_A B_q = A_p \otimes_{A_p} B_q=B_q$.

Comment: Great, I think I get it now. Thank you very much, :*

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: Hi Manos, I have a real quick question, so I think I'm posting it here instead of creating a new topic. So, say I have a $B-$module $M$, and I have a ring homomorphism $f:A\to B$, so I can view $M$ as an $A-$module, too. Say, if I have $S$ a multiplicative subset of $A$, and I localize $M$ at $S$, it should be $S^{-1}M = M \otimes_A S^{-1}A$, and if I take $M$ to be a $B-$module, and instead of localizing it at $S$, I localize it at $f(S)$, so $f(S)^{-1} = M \otimes_B f(S)^{-1}B$. So, basically, they are the same, right? I mean $M \otimes_B f(S)^{-1}B = M \otimes_A S^{-1}A$. 2 are the same?

Comment: @user49685: Yes, they are isomorphic. Try proving that. If you use the tensor product characterization of localization try to show the existence of an invertible morphism between the two. If you use the definition of localization (this may be easier) try to directly set up an isomorphism between the two.

Comment: @user49685: The intuition is that essentially we are allowing denominators that take the same values at both cases.